# Set the type name for an object

Tags: javascript

I'm defining a JavaScript function like this:

```
function F() {
}
```

It gets some more properties and methods through a prototype object. When it's time to use the function, I'd like to see the object name, like for Array or other built-in objects. But I always see "Object" as the object type.

```
var i = new F();
console.log(i);
// Object { }
// wanted: something with "F" instead of "Object"

var a = [];
console.log(a);
// Array []

console.log(document);
// HTMLDocument about:newtab
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

I found several other questions here but none had the desired effect. I'm not too experienced with the whole prototype and `new` thing in JavaScript so I don't know the correct terms to find relevant results.

My function `F` must still be callable as a regular function, so I don't think I am interested in creating a `class` as supported in newer web browsers.

My code targets any web browsers that's in wide use today, which is probably Chrome, Firefox, Safari and a bunch of Android apps with unknown internals (Samsung?).

Comment: `a.constructor.name`?

Comment: try console.log(JSON.stringify(i));

Comment: @Yoandry Collazo that will output `{}`, how is that supposed to show the constructor name...?

Comment: @Jan Stránský: Yes but the question was how to influence the output of `console.log` when just passed the object.

Comment: @JanStránský That doesn't have any effect here (set on the instance or the function).

Comment: @ygoe "What can I do to get the desired output?" - you can `console.log(i.constructor.name)`. Why do you want it btw (have not found it in the OP)

Answer (score 2):

The display name of objects is controlled by their [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) behavior. The default implementation of `.toString()` uses the value returned by the [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) property (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString_to_detect_object_class)), which will be found on the `Object` prototype if not defined explicitly for your type. Thus it will have the value "Object" unless you override it.

```js
function F() { }

let i = new F();
console.log(i.toString()); //[object Object]

F.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "F";
console.log(i.toString()); //[object F]
```

Comment: This only works when explicitly calling `toString`. It has no effect on `console.log(i)`.

Comment: Hm, my last comment only seems to apply to Firefox. In Chrome, no such words appear at all. No "Array" and no "Object". And when logging the object, it automatically appears with its function name, without any `toString`.

Comment: @ygoe Yes, each browser has a different implementation of logging objects without .toString(). By setting the toStringTag you should cover pretty much all cases where a "class name" may show up in any browser.